# EhCache to put new element to disk if memory store full

Tags: ehcache

I would like to use EhCache in combination of memory and disk cache. EhCache should move **new** elements to disk when memory is full. e.g. I have 100 elements in ehCache memory store and tries to put 101st element and if memory is full then put 101st element to disk not 1st element.

Could you please let me know the cache configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Ehcache no longer works that way. The tiering model introduced in Ehcache 2.6 and used since then will always store ALL mappings into the *lower* tier, disk in your case.

The reason is predictable latency. If Ehcache waited for the memory tier to be full before using the disk, you would see a latency increase maybe at the worst time for your application. While the model were all mappings are written to disk gives you the upper bound for the write latency, while reads may be faster for hot value that are available in memory directly.

Comment: It seems like the 2.x documentation of Ehcache does not mention thoses changes: "Disk store – Backs up in-memory data and provides overflow capacity to the other tiers." (http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.4/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-tiers_about_storage_tiers.html%23)

Comment: Its quite frustrating when they miss out to mention such important changes. :/